# Sony vaio fit is turning on only on 2nd power button press

Tags: windows, sony-vaio

I have Sony vaio fit laptop.
This problem is arised a few days back. Laptop is turning on  only on 2nd power button press.
When powerbutton is pressed for the first time, the vaio starting logo is shown and laptop turns off.
By the next power button hit, it starts normaly. But a bit slow than usual booting. I dont know whats going on. Please help me.

Edit - I shutdown it properly.

Comment: Do you mean **Assist** button about another power button?

Comment: its not about another power button. I mean that when i pressed power button for the 2nd time

Comment: I just came across your question, which you edited back in October.  Does the edit mean that you were able to fix the problem or was it a response to the answer that the issue was not as suggested?  Did you manage to solve the problem or do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you don't actually shutdown your computer. You just close the lid right?

Right. So when you close the lid it sleeps/hibernates. You open the lid, it starts waking up, then you press the power button causing a shutdown. Then you press it again, causing it to turn on.

If you don't close the lid, but you still don't shutdown, then it just sleeps/hibernates on it's own. Then, while waiting for you to hit a key or click the mouse, you push the power button, cause it to shutdown. Then you press it again to turn it on.

Comment: I dont know what happened. It may be a bug with windows. I have reinstalled windows. Now its ok. Its not about closing the lid or hibernation.